# union of two rectangles.write a program to find the smallest possible rectangle enclosing the 2 given rectangles

Tags: c

Given the coordinates of the lower left corner (x,y), the length (l) and width(w) of 2 rectangles, write a program to find the smallest possible rectangle enclosing the 2 given rectangles.

Input and Output Format:

The 1st line of the input consists of 4 integers separated by a space that correspond to x, y, l and w of the first rectangle.

The 2nd line of the input consists of 4 integers separated by a space that correspond to x, y, l and w of the second rectangle.

Output consists of 4 integers that correspond to x, y, l and w of the Union rectangle.

Sample Input :

3 8 1515

2 6 10 10

Sample Output:

2 6 16 17

I am not able to figure out the logic....I am not asking for the whole program,just want help on the logic part...

UPDATE:
here is my program which is now working...thank u all for your help :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x1, x2, y1, y2, l1, l2, w1, w2, xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin;
  scanf(“%d %d %d %d\n”,&x1,&y1,&l1,&w1);
  scanf(“%d %d %d %d\n”,&x2,&y2,&l2,&w2);
  xmin = x1 < x2 ? x1 : x2;
  ymin = y1 < y2 ? y1 : y2;
  int b = x1 + l1;
  int c = x2 + l2;
  xmax = b > c ? b : c;
  int d = y1 + w1;
  int e = y2 + w2;
  ymax = d > e ? d : e;
  int l = xmax - xmin;
  int w = ymax - ymin;
  printf(“%d %d %d %d”,xmin,ymin,l,w);
  return 0;
}
```

can't figure out the problem in my program.. :(

Comment: hint: try converting from `x,y,l,w` to `xMin,yMin,xMax,yMax` and see how this helps your understanding (a drawing may help you more than the solution code)

Comment: What I've never understood in these questions is why the order is `x, y, l, w` instead of `x, y, w, h`... wouldn't it make more sense to have `x-reference, y-reference, x-size, y-size` than `x-reference, y-reference, y-size, x-size`? Why are the width and height always swapped?

Comment: Try drawing a picture with two rectangles.

Comment: This problem is really more interesting if one answers "find the smallest rectangle" rather than the "find the smallest rectangle that fits as a "x, y, l and w".  Consider 2 small rectangles spaced far apart diagonally from each other.The "smallest enclosing rectangle" would be aligned at that diagonal.

Comment: This question should probably be clarified as to whether the input rectangles and the expected output rectangle are intended to be axis-aligned (as it seems to be, but is not clearly stated). Otherwise, there are an infinite number of rectangles with a given lower left corner and dimensions, and, as pointed out by @chux, the best solution is likely not axis-aligned...

Comment: @twalberg Unfortunately, the post does say "Output consists of 4 integers that correspond to x, y, l and w of the Union rectangle.", so the goal is certainly not the smallest, but axis-aligned.  Yet thanks for also thinking outside the box - angled or not.

Comment: @Jashaszun Actually it looks like the specs here *are*  x,y,w,h, but the nomenclature used is strange. In the instructions it looks like "l" is the length of the rectangle along the x axis, and "w" is the width (height) along the y axis. You can figure this out by examining the given inputs and expected output.

Comment: @ BeyelerStudios what do you mean by xMin,yMin,xMax,yMax??

Comment: This is a really easy problem. Use a pencil. Use your mind.

Comment: Is there a problem with your spacebar when writing code?

Comment: Note: 1) Remove `'\n'` from `scanf(“%d %d %d %d\n”,&x1,&y1,&l1,&w1);` 2) Do not use smart quotes `“”`, use `"`.

Comment: "its showing wrong answer."  --> What are the inputs and what is the wrong answer than it is showing?

Comment: `int e = y1 + w1;` --> `int e = y2 + w2;`.  `int c = x2 + l1;` --> `int c = x2 + l2;`

Answer (score 2):

Given the location of the lower left corner, the length, and the width, you can determine the other three points.  Do this for both rectangles.  For example, given `x1`, `y1`, `l1`, `w1`, `p1 = (x1,y1)`, `p2 = (x1,y1+l1)`, `p3 = (x1+w1,y1)`, `p4 = (x1+w1,y1+l1)`.

Now look at the eight points you have and find the smallest X (minX) and smallest Y (minY) among them, along with the largest X (maxX) and largest Y (maxY).  Note that none of these values necessarily come from the same point.

Your results are now `minX`, `minY`, `maxY - minY`, and `maxX - minX`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming positive lengths and widths:

1. Find lowest `xmin`: minimum of `x1` and `x2`.  Same for `ymin`.  Now the output rectangle corner is known.
2. Find highest `xmax`: maximum of `x1 + l1` and `x2 + l1`.  Same for `ymax` using `y` values and widths.
3. Determine output rectangle dimensions: `length`: difference of `xmax` and `xmin`.  Same for `width` and `ymax, ymin`.

It is that simple.

Comment: i have  used the same logic in my program...please go through my program...I have added the program now..

Comment: @620d Comments added above - suggest closer attention to detail.

Comment: thanks a lot buddy...i figured out the mistakes and the program is accepted now.. :)

Answer (score 2):

1)Find Xmin = minimum of X1 and X2.

2)Find Ymin = minimum of Y1 and Y2.

3)Find Xmax = maximum of (X1+L1) and (X2+L2)

4)Find Ymax = maximum of (Y1+W1) and (Y2+w2)

5)Find Length = Difference between Xmax and Xmin

6)Find Width = Difference between Ymax and Ymin

7)Final Result is (Xmin,Ymin,Length,Width)

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. calculate upper-right corner of two rectangles
2. You must to Sort the x's coordinates, and the y's coordinates.
3. The smallest rectangle enclosing the 2 given rectangles has:

   - lower-left corner: `(x1,y1)`
   - upper-right corner: `(x4,y4)`
4. calculate size.

See image:

[image]

Comment: OP says "I am not asking for the whole program".  Suggest removing code.